# PyGame/Python 3.3 - Video Playback

Tags: video, python-3.x, pygame

I've been making a simple tower defense game as my first project with pygame and Python 3.3. Pretty much finished it for all it is, but I was thinking of adding a short video as an intro to the game. So, I looked it up on the web and saw that there was the pygame.movie module for this purpose and started trying to use it.

After reading about the use, I think I made use of the module correctly (and I ensured to ffmpeg -convert my file to MPEG1). When I tried to run the code I got an error that stated that there was no module called "pygame.movie". I tried to "manually" import it with an import statement as well, but still no luck.

I read from a post here:
 http://python-forum.org/viewtopic.php?t=10625&p=13394
(by metulburr » Tue Jan 21, 2014 1:01 pm-)

I saw that he has an identical error message to myself there.

I was wondering if anyone could shed some light, or at least point me at the explanation for what might be wrong here. Is it just no longer supported with the newer Python? Or am I missing something.

Also, if you know of any good alternatives in the event that pygame.movie is not available I would appreciate your opinion!

This error message is actually from the site linked above and not from my code.
But the error message is virtually identical.
/////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
test3.py:10: RuntimeWarning: use movie: No module named 'pygame.movie'
(ImportError: No module named 'pygame.movie')
  movie = pg.movie.Movie(filename)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test3.py", line 10, in <module>
    movie = pg.movie.Movie(filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 102, in __getattr__
    raise NotImplementedError(MissingPygameModule)
NotImplementedError: movie module not available
(ImportError: No module named 'pygame.movie')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pygame movie module is very experimental/alpha. I get the same error on a Mac, and from what I can tell that's because the Movie module isn't implemented for the Mac platform.

I have been searching for days for a video/movie playback solution for Pygame, especially one that doesn't require converting videos to MPEG-1 format. It seems that the only way to do it is to use some other video player (pyglet, etc.) and then to copy the pixels from your video player to a Pygame surface. (This works ok for us because we only need the video, not audio. I'm not sure how it would work with audio.)

Comment: Is this still the case? Just curious if you've found any solutions to OP's original query...

Comment: Yeah it's still the case. Worse now actually, as the Pygame movie module has been pulled out of Pygame altogether.

For our project, we're moving off of Pygame and replacing it with PySDL2.

Comment: thanks.  I'll take a look at PySDL2 in the meantime.